# Audio Amplifier which can Supply 20W to 20-40 Ohm Load

Tags: amplifier, audio

I've looked around for a while, and my question appears to be very specific and I was hoping that someone who knew more about audio amplifiers could help.

I'm doing some research assistance where sound sources with impedances from 20-40 Ohms are going to need to be driven at 20W. Based on some Googling I've done, this appears to be very specialized. Even very expensive amplifiers are only rated with 4 to 8 Ohm load speakers. The amplifiers need to be suitable for audio (passband from maybe 100Hz to about 25kHz), and I've found nothing so far.

My question boils down to this: does anyone know where I might find such an amplifier, or whether I need to construct my own? I'd like to spend less than $100 on the amplifier, which may be impossible.

Comment: You can also use a pair of more modest amplifiers in bridge mode to double the available voltage, without having to worry about their drive current rating, as each amp will see a 10-20 ohm load.

Comment: @Brian: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=A0LEVoAfAsZWwW0AkyYnnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEycXU4aDk2BGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQjExMTVfMQRzZWMDc2M-?qid=20121016071820AAwtyWJ I did a quick search on how to bridge two separate amplifiers and found this immediately. Do you think it applies here?

Comment: If you pick the wrong amplifiers it might. Bridging two channels of a stereo amp (shared ground) would be fine : you just need a way to invert the signal to feed the second amp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ordinary audio power amplifier should be able to handle your application.  For example, an amplifier rated for 100 watts into 8 ohms has to supply an output voltage of about 28 VRMS.  This voltage, with a 40 ohm load, will develop 20  watts. With a 20 ohm load, it could provide 40 watts. There should be no problem using a higher impedance load with typical audio power amplifiers. The only drawback is that you need an amplifier with a higher power rating than you need for your load.

Comment: I'd Like to add on that it needs to **NOT** be a Class-D amp (i.e. He should find one that's a Class-AB). But I like your answer otherwise.

Comment: @Dave: What's wrong with using a class-D amplifier?

Comment: @DaveTweed, In a Class-D amplifier, the load is part of the LC filter on the output of the switching transistors. Changing the load will result in changes to frequency response. Moving a few % up or down doesn't do much harm, but 20-40 ohms is around 300-500% different. At those limits the high frequency response of the filter will actually pass **more** harmonic content and may destabilize the amplifier.

Comment: @Barry Exactly 20W into 40 Ohms for an amp rated at 100W into 8 Ohms no less! Thank you. I did some basic calculations and was thinking that maybe a regular amplifier would work, but wasn't sure if I was missing some intricacies of the circuitry.

Comment: @Dave Thanks! I'll avoid Class-D and look for Class-AB.

Comment: I meant to type "more harmonic content around the cut-off frequency" and by that I mean that it will actually resonate and produce a gain just before the cut-off frequency. This isn't good unless you really enjoy your 20Khz content to be around 5-10dB higher than everything else.

Comment: @Dave: Thank you. Dropping a comment like that into the conversation with no explanation is not very useful to the site.

Comment: @DaveTweed, asking for an expansion to the answer is hardly useless. If Barry wants to add it in, he can. If not, then xcnmoore will still see it and can ask a new question about *why* class-D wouldn't work for his application, which would then lead to a good and full explanation about how class-D works compared to Class-AB (which is a *huge topic*) and how the load would effect the frequency response and there could be graphs and everything else to prove the theory. Quite frankly, as my explanation stands it crude and underwhelming to a full answer. But again, he didn't ask for that.

Comment: @Dave: If you had included your second comment into your first to begin with, there would have been no issue -- it's more than enough to explain what you meant. You've been here, what, about 2 months? And you want to take on a diamond moderator about what constitutes a good answer or comment on the site? Just to be clear, I'm not angry with you, just amused :-)

Comment: @DaveTweed, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35933/audio-amplifier-and-stepping-outside-the-bounds-of-a-question please join this so that we don't clog up this answer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem, You can drive a 40 ohm source with an an amp specified for 8 ohms... you just need to make sure you have enough voltage.  V^2/R = 20 Watts.